# DRF Serializer field for intermediate mode

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am making am app to control the presence of students. I have 4 models:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)

class Justification(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)

class Session(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    present = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
    absences = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name='absences_set', through='Absence')

class Absence(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    atleta = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    justification = models.ForeignKey(Justification, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The models have more fields and different names (I translated the names to English) but this is basically it.

I am using DRF framework to make an API. I have setup the endpoints (and serializers) for `Student`, `Justification` and `Absence` but I can't figure out how to make the serializer for the `Session` model. I want it to work when someone makes the following `POST` (I only need an endpoint to create `Session`s) request (I am using a `ViewSet` for the view):

```
{
    "date": "2019-02-01T10:08:52-02:00"
    "present": [
        2
    ],
    "absences": [
        {
          "student": 1,
          "justification": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

But the absences are not created. How can I make this nested relationship work?

ps: I can only make one request that's why I don't want to make one request to create a `Session` and then many requests to create `Absence`s and need it all together. If there is a way to create all of them on the same request (but not only the same JSON object) I am okay with this solution

Answer (score 0):

If i understand properly you want to create corresponding absences and season at same `Season` end-point. I think `Justification` and `Student` both model serve same, they are just student's instance and keep student information if i am not wrong. So i don't think there is actually any need to keep `Justfication` model. Corresponding `absences` ( students ) in `Season Model` need to ask for `Justification`. So my advice to keep model structure as like these

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)

class Session(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    present = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
    absences = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name='absences_set', through='Absence')

class Absence(models.Model):
    session = models.OneToOneField(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # You can also keep Foreign-key
    atleta = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And then there are two possible way to create Absence model instance corresponding to `Season` Post endpoint. We can overwrite the `post` method of `SeasonViewset` and write our logic there or even can overwrite the `SeasonSrealizer-create` method to do same.

My preferable option is to overwrite post method of `SeasonViewset`. And these can be done as like following  - over writing DRF [CreateMixins](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py)

```
class SeasonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet): 
     # your declare serializers and others thing

     def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        season_instance = self.perform_create(serializer)
        # creating Absence's instance and you need to add other fields as necessary
        Absence.objects.create(season=season_instance)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Justification is the reason of the absence. It's not the same as the Student

Comment: I am working with your solution. How can I use the Absence serializer to create an Absence related to the Session?

Comment: I was confuse about your Post data, then justification should be like proper reason not just like `student's id`. I think then those should serve from a normalize model, where we store absence students ids and their justification. I am trying to update my answer.

Comment: The id in the POST data is the id of the justification not the student's id. Sorry if it was confuse. But with your solution I am already starting to make it work. One question: why your preferable option is to overwrite post method? instead of the serialiser's create?

Comment: Sorry i don't get that. Then its ok. This is because you can use that serializer in other logical operation where you don't won't to this coupling  operation. For creating Season this is obvious to create Absence.

Comment: But wouldn't the create method of the serializer only be called to create a Session?